# PHP extensions not found

Tags: php, php-extension

PHP keeps failing and telling me that its not finding the /ext/php_mssql.dll for some reason. Obviously, I checked the folder and it is very much there. I'm not sure why it is failing. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I put the ntwdblib.dll into my php directory and the error that was giving went from "bad gateway. the specified cgi application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of http headers. the headers it did return are "php failed to start: could not load /ext/php_mssql.dll" to not returning any headers at all.

> HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway The
>   specified CGI application misbehaved
>   by not returning a complete set of
>   HTTP headers. The headers it did
>   return are "".

Answer (score 2):

When I get this situation, it's usually because of one of two reasons:

- Path problems. The working directory might not be what you think it is, so a relative path ends up somewhere else than intented. There were some other config settings about this though;
- The extension you're loading requires some other .DLL's, but can't find them - thus fails to load. PHP doesn't report this condition correctly (it just says - failed to load).

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth checking that you have ntwdblib.dll in c:\windows\system32 or in your PHP directory - there should be one that comes with SQL Server. I also found the one sometimes bundled with PHP did not work.

Comment: i found a copy and placed it in my php directory, and now i get a different error.